# WPF System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser not rendering link buttons

Tags: html, css, webbrowser-control, doctype, x-ua-compatible

I have a web page that I display in a WPF WebBrowser control within a desktop application. I just updated the webpage to use styled buttons instead of the default gray buttons by changing from an asp.net Button type to an asp.net LinkButton and applying a CSS style to it:

```
    a.btnSave
    {
        background: url(Resources/Images/btnSave.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 75px;
        height: 23px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    a.btnSave:hover {background-position: 0 -23px;}

    a.btnCancel
    {
        background: url(Resources/Images/btnCancel.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 75px;
        height: 23px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    a.btnCancel:hover {background-position: 0 -23px;}

    a.btnReset
    {
        background: url(Resources/Images/btnReset.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 75px;
        height: 23px;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    a.btnReset:hover {background-position: 0 -23px;}
```

...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="OnSubmit()" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Text=" " />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btnCancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" OnClientClick="OnSubmit()" CausesValidation="False" Text=" " />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnReset" runat="server" CssClass="btnReset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" OnClientClick="OnSubmit()" CausesValidation="False" Text=" " />
```

When I view the page in IE 8 (or firefox), the buttons appear correctly. But when I load the page in the WebBrowser control within the app, the buttons are missing. If I hover over where they should be I do not receive the Hand icon so it's not just that the images are not being loaded. When I view the source, the anchor tags are there and if I copy the source and save it to an HTML file and open that in a browser window, they do appear correctly. In the past, I've had trouble with the WebBrowser not dispalying floating divs the same way a browser does and had to switch to a table layout. Does it not support the inline-block display type or something?

If it matters, this is the doctype declared for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I just discovered that if I turn compatibility view ON in IE, the buttons disappear. Could this be the problem?

Comment: It is using compatibility mode and if I turn it off using a registry key, or setting <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> on my page the buttons appear! That leaves me with these questions: Doesn't my !DOCTYPE specify to use the latest HTML5/CSS3 standards? If so, what's wrong with my code? Why does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> cause it to work correctly but <!DOCTYPE html> alone does not?

Comment: The new tags aren't really relevant. We're not talking about HTML5 or CSS3 here.

Comment: @BoltClock Please explain why we are not. It seems to be the factor determining whether the buttons display or not. I want to do this in a html5/css3 compliant way.

Comment: Because you're not writing HTML5/CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock From what I've gathered from [MS articles on IE compatibility modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we're talking about compatibility with html5/css3 standards...at least we might be if we were addressing the question. I tagged them to try to bring in people with knowledge of that topic. I untagged them to try to steer this to a constructive discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was using compatability mode by default which was not honoring the styles. Changing it to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

fixed it.

Comment: How would that fix it in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

The WPF WebBrowser will by default run in IE7 compatibility mode.
If you have control over the web site you could add a <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"...> tag as described in one of the other answers here.
I tried to do this in a solution that runs a WPF application + a web application.
The client machine was running IE11.
Adding the meta tag did not solve a problem related to the user agent string though.
The WebBrowser still reported it to be IE7.
The solution I found was to configure the WebBrowser in registry like this:

```
Registry.SetValue(
@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,
int.MaxValue);
```